# Prometheus relabel_configs issue

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

My labels:

```
__address__: "https://example.com/health"
__metrics_path__: "/probe"
__param_module: "http_200"
__scheme__: "http"
job: "black-box"
```

My config:

```
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    target_label: __param_target
  - source_labels: [__param_target]
    target_label: instance
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    regex:  '\/health'
    replacement: 'my new label'
    target_label: service
  - source_labels: [module]
    target_label: __param_module
  - target_label: __address__
    replacement: newdomain:9115
```

I cannot understand why regex: `'\/health'` does not match and the service target is not created.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `regex` should match the whole string, wchich is constructed from values of labels passed to `source_labels` list concatenated with the `separator` (by default it is set to `;`). So, in your case the `regex` should look like `regex: ".+/health"` .

P.S. I'd recommend using [this service for debugging of Prometheus target relabeling](https://play.victoriametrics.com/select/accounting/1/6a716b0f-38bc-4856-90ce-448fd713e3fe/target-relabel-debug).